# Arrow and canc no more works as indeed

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vim

My problem is that, out of nowhere my arrow keys and the canc button no more work on Ubuntu

If I'm using the terminal the arrow keys, instead of moving left and right or let me use previous commands, they print A or B or C or D. The canc print 2~

I also use Sublime text and, the arrows, instead of moving the cursors around, actually highlight the text. The canc deletes an entire row.

I've tried to install `vim` with no luck

I think I have wrongly press a combination of keys that made something wrong but I don't know how to revert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various key combinations I figured it out that pressing 5 times <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> reverts the issue.